# How to access Camera, Calendar, Photos, Microphone, Location, Media Library, Motion, Speech Recognition, SiriKit, TV Provider in iOS 10

Tags: camera, contacts, ios10, privacy, setting

I am developing my app for iOS 10, but my default iOS functionality extensions not working well. Like am not able to access camera, Microphone and media Library. Every time it got crashed. I have written all, but nothing working.

```
case .Authorized:
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        break
    //handle authorized status
    case .Denied, .Restricted :
        print("Denied")

        let alertController = UIAlertController (title: appName, message: "Go to Settings?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .Default) { (_) -> Void in
            let settingsUrl = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
            if let url = settingsUrl {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
            }
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(settingsAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A significant change in iOS 10 is that you must declare ahead of time any access to private data or your App will crash.** The fix is quick but easy to overlook if the usage is not a major feature of an App so here is your reminder if you are planning an iOS 10 migration.

**Don’t Forget Your Purpose Strings**

Once you link with iOS 10 **you must declare access to any user private data types. You do this by adding a usage key to your app’s Info.plist together with a purpose string.** The list of frameworks that count as private data is a long one:

***Contacts, Calendar, Reminders, Photos, Bluetooth Sharing, Microphone, Camera, Location, Health, HomeKit, Media Library, Motion, CallKit, Speech Recognition, SiriKit, TV Provider***.

If you are using one of these frameworks and fail to declare the usage your app will crash when it first makes the access. The crash log helpfully tells you which key you are missing. For example, this is the result of accessing the camera without adding the key to Info.plist:

**This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app’s Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.**

To avoid the crash we need to add the suggested key to ‘Info.plist’ (Xcode 8 already contains the full list of possible keys):[image]

The system shows the purpose string when asking the user to allow access (so you may want to localize it):
[image]

**The direction from Apple is clear. If you access private data declare your intentions up front or expect your App to crash.**

You can check all privacy settings key for apple documentation : [Privacy setting keys for iOS10](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)